# How to use WITH clause in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, common-table-expression, query-builder

I have SQL query (see example).
But I can't find a way how I can write it in Query Builder.
Do you have any ideas how is it possible?

```sql
WITH main AS (
    SELECT id FROM table1
)
SELECT * FROM table2
WHERE 
  table2.id IN (SELECT * FROM main)
```

I want to get format like:

```sql
$latestPosts = DB::table('posts')
                   ->select('user_id', DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as last_post_created_at'))
                   ->where('is_published', true)
                   ->groupBy('user_id');

$users = DB::table('users')
        ->joinSub($latestPosts, 'latest_posts', function ($join) {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'latest_posts.user_id');
        })->get();
```

but for WITH

Comment: Does your query work in MySQL?
Isn't what you showed a one to many relationship? You can use the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) for good examples.

Comment: I don't know about MySQL and WITH clause. I use it in PostgerSQL.
Of course, my real task is'n so simple like example. Real task more complex, but I simplify it for the Question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel has no native support for common table expressions.

I've created a package for it: https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-cte

You can use it like this:

```php
$query = DB::table('table1')->select('id');

$result = DB::table('table2')
    ->withExpression('main', $query)
    ->whereIn('table2.id', DB::table('main')->select('id'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: Yes, beautiful. Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 0):

Query builder has to be compatible with multiple database engines (mysql, postgresql, sql lite, sql server) and as such only offers support for common functionality.

Assuming your query returns data, you may be able to use the `DB:select()` method to execute a [raw query](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#running-queries).

`$data = DB::select('WITH main AS (SELECT id FROM table1), SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2.id IN (SELECT * FROM main)');`

The DB:select method also accepts a second parameter for using named bindings.

Alternatively there are packages available such as [laravel-cte](https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-cte) that will add the functionality to Eloquent/ Query Builder.